# Find "Null" occurences Ranges grouped by id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Imagine I have this kind of Sql server table:

```
Timestamp   TrendAggregationId  Value   Quality


2020-02-10 13:55:00.000 1   15     100
2020-02-10 14:00:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:05:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:10:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:15:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:20:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:25:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:30:00.000 1   30      100
2020-02-10 14:35:00.000 1   40      99
2020-02-10 14:40:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:45:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:50:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 14:55:00.000 1   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:00:00.000 2   20     100
2020-02-10 15:05:00.000 2   99     100
2020-02-10 15:10:00.000 2   110    100
2020-02-10 15:15:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:20:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:25:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:30:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:35:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:40:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:45:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:50:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 15:55:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 16:00:00.000 2   NULL    0
2020-02-10 16:05:00.000 2   NULL    0
```

I would like to retrieve all NULLs row time range (start/end) grouped for any AggregationID

for this example something like this:

```
TrendAggregationId   Start                            End
1                  2020-02-10 14:00:00.000        2020-02-10 14:25:00.000
1                  2020-02-10 14:40:00.000        2020-02-10 14:55:00.000
2                  2020-02-10 15:15:00.000        2020-02-10 16:05:00.000
```

Do you have any suggestions?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of non-null values up to each row.  That defines a group.  Then aggregate (and filter):

```
select TrendAggregationId, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by TrendAggregationId order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by TrendAggregationId, grp
```

Answer (score 0):

With `SUM()` window function:

```
select TrendAggregationId, 
  min(Timestamp) [Start], 
  max(Timestamp) [End]
from (
  select *, 
    sum(case when Value is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by TrendAggregationId order by Timestamp) grp
  from tablename
) t
where Value is null
group by TrendAggregationId, grp
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3126523f16550ebe3070db16879a117).
Results:

```
> TrendAggregationId | Start                   | End                    
> -----------------: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
>                  1 | 2020-02-10 14:00:00.000 | 2020-02-10 14:25:00.000
>                  1 | 2020-02-10 14:40:00.000 | 2020-02-10 14:55:00.000
>                  2 | 2020-02-10 15:15:00.000 | 2020-02-10 16:05:00.000
```